# Lyx - Bibliography order

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

I'm using a Lyx 2.0 for my thesis and I have a problem. The bibliography order is the bibliography order of figures index, and not the order of citations in text. Can I solve this?

I use an external file (by JabRef).
An example: [document](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7968620/newfile2.pdf)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: -1 It is not polite to cross-post without linking to your other posts. This can waste people's time and can inhibit their attempts to help you. Here is (one of) your other post(s): http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=24041&sid=b9a66eff092a797ffcbc6d1880ae9a5b

Comment: I already read the many different styles, but, for example, the unsrt order bibliography through order in document (include list of figures), and I want the order only by order that appears in text.

Comment: Did adding `\usepackage{notoccite}` to the LaTeX preamble fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your `\bibliographystyle` selection.  Are you sure you are using the proper one?  It's just a matter of choosing the one your supervisor has assigned to you.

There are lots of bibliography style variations, and the package [`natbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) works pretty well when dealing with lots of them.  I highly recommend you take a look at it and the different styles.